# Negation of an Object Property

Tags: owl, protege, object-property

I have an Object Property IsMarriedWith, I want to create a Class "Single" to get non married individuals, I defined its "Equivalent To" like this:

```
IsMarriedWith max 0 Thing
```

And i also tried this:

```
not (IsMarriedWith min 1 Thing)
```

But none of those expressions returns a result, how to define this class?

Comment: "return" by what? How do you query it?

Comment: Note, in OWL there is the Open World Assumption, please read about it and you'll understand

Comment: I mean return individuals after reasoning

Comment: Yes i know to open world assumption, but i think there is no impact of this with what i want to do

Comment: Open world assumption will always have an impact as it is a basic assumption of the reasoner.

Comment: For anyone to help you to understand why these sets are empty, you need to give the details of how you defined these classes and which individuals you defined. Please provide a minimal complete example ontology with the inferences you expected.

Comment: @user4374239 of course the Open World Assumption will be reason why it doesn't work. Absence of information can't be treated by the reasoner as negation, thus, only because there is no such fact in your ontology for an individual `Bob` being `IsMarriedWith` somebody, doesn't mean it doesn't exists anywhere else - it is so far just unknown